# Order class by field

Tags: scala

I have created a class `Path` which should be uniquely identifiable by `occupation` and `last`.

```
case class Path(occupation: BitSet, last: Int) {
      var cost = 0
      def setCost(cost: Int) {
          this.cost = cost
      }

      def getCost(): Int = {
          return cost
      }
  }
}
```

Also, I would like it to be sortable by `count`, which I made a field.

```
implicit val pathOrd = Ordering.by((p: Path) => p.getCost)
```

The problem is that when I am sorting it(as you can see in the line above), I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` on that line.

Why is this happening?
Can I store my data better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives no exceptions to me using this code:

```
@ class Path(occupation: BitSet, last: Int) {
        var cost = 0
        def setCost(cost: Int) {
            this.cost = cost
        }

        def getCost(): Int = {
            return cost
        }
    }
defined class Path
@ List(new Path(BitSet(), 3))
res6: List[Path] = List(cmd5$Path@3ef8de39)
@ implicit val pathOrd = Ordering.by((p: Path) => p.getCost)
pathOrd: Ordering[Path] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@5f478e42
@ res6.sorted
res9: List[Path] = List(cmd5$Path@3ef8de39)
```

You are missing `val` for `occupation` and `last`

```
class Path(val occupation: BitSet, val last: Int)
```

I would suggest you to create a case class

```
case class Path(occupation: BitSet, last: Int)
```

It will have `equals`, and `hashCode` based on it's fields, `toString`, `apply`, `unapply` and `copy` methods.

I am not sure if you really need to modify the `cost`, if it is calculated based on other values you could make it a method

```
case class Path(occupation: BitSet, last: Int) {
  def cost: Int = 42
}
```

if it's not then it should be a field. I want to encourage you to use immutable structures, which would mean doing:

```
case class Path(occupation: BitSet, last: Int, cost: Int)
```

Adding a field with setter and getter in scala is as simple as this:

```
class Path(val occupation: BitSet, val last: Int) {
  var cost = 0
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
val path = new Path(BitSet(), 3)
path.cost = 12
println(path.cost)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler version of the code that uses Scala's conversions for using var to indicate mutable state in a class:

```
case class Path
(occupation: BitSet, // Immutable (will never change) 
var cost: Int = 0, // Mutable 
var last: Int = 0 // Mutable
)

// Implementing the Ordering TypeClass
implicit val pathOrd = Ordering.by((p: Path) => p.cost)

val t = new Path(BitSet(1,2), 0, 0)

t.cost = 2 // changing cost
val data = Seq(new Path(BitSet(1,2), 0, 0), new Path(BitSet(1), 3, 0), new Path(BitSet(1), 2, 0))

println(data.sorted)
```